# How can I convert string variable into byte type in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography

I want to encrypt a messages which I got from user input using Cryptography:

I have the following simple code:

```
import os
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
backend = default_backend()
messages = input("Please, insert messages to encrypt: ")
key = os.urandom(24)
print(key)
cipher = Cipher(algorithms.TripleDES(key), modes.ECB(), backend=backend)
encryptor = cipher.encryptor()
cryptogram = encryptor.update(b"a secret message") + encryptor.finalize()
print(cryptogram)
```

When I hard code the messages <kbd>"a secret message"</kbd> with <kbd>b</kbd> prefix in the code it works fine.
What I wanted to do is to use <kbd>messages</kbd>variable to get the text from user input.

```
messages = input("Please, insert messages to encrypt: ")
```

I've tried several ways to covert the string type from the input to byte type and pass it to encryptor.update method but nothing works for me.

```
messages = input(b"Please, insert messages to encrypt: ")
cryptogram = encryptor.update(byte, message) + encryptor.finalize()
...
```

Versions:

Python 3.7.0

Cryptography 2.4

Mac OS

Comment: This was trivial to search. Please look for a duplicate question the next time. It will save you the effort of writing up a long question and us the effort of closing it.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, sorry but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Oct  2 13:23:27 2018

@author: myhaspl
@email:myhaspl@myhaspl.com
@blog:dmyhaspl.github.io
"""
import os
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import padding
padder = padding.PKCS7(128).padder()
backend = default_backend()
key = os.urandom(32)
iv = os.urandom(16)
cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CBC(iv), backend=backend)
encryptor = cipher.encryptor()
messages = input("Please input your message: ")
messages=bytes(messages,"utf-8")
padded_data = padder.update(messages )
padded_data += padder.finalize()
print(padded_data)
ct = encryptor.update(padded_data) + encryptor.finalize()
decryptor = cipher.decryptor()
decryptorData=decryptor.update(ct) + decryptor.finalize()
unpadder = padding.PKCS7(128).unpadder()
data = unpadder.update(decryptorData)
print(data + unpadder.finalize())

Please input your message: hello,world! I am dmyhaspl.my blog is dmyhaspl.github.io
b'hello,world! I am dmyhaspl.my blog is dmyhaspl.github.io\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08'
b'hello,world! I am dmyhaspl.my blog is dmyhaspl.github.io'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'a secret message'
b = s.encode('utf-8')
```